# Sketch: Layer Mask

Tags: mask, sketch-app, fill

I'm trying to fill a layer with an image using a shape as a layer mask. I would like to have the inner shadow I added to the shape show once I fill it with an image. However, as expected, the image covers it. I tried with an image fill but I'm not able to control what part of the image shows within the shape. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply duplicate the shape (remove the fill and add the inner shadow) and place it on top of the masked shape. Like so:

[image]